# How to plot file sizes

Tags: data-visualization

I have data about ~18.000 files, mostly name, and size. I would like to plot it with Mathplotlib. Not sure what would be the best option.

```
df_final.head(2)
                       file_sizes_clean                    number_of_files
folder1/               [36829.0, 38711.0, 0, 349159, ...]   9
folder2/               [71318.0, 46944.0,... ]              6
```

Collecting all the file sizes into a single np.array:

```
from scipy import stats
x = np.array(sizes_flat)
stats.describe(x)

DescribeResult(nobs=18664, minmax=(3336.0, 8876007.0), 
mean=280316.77716459497, variance=445060834502.10297, 
skewness=4.744572944478072, kurtosis=29.465744857449934)
```

Trying to plot it:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, figsize=(20, 8))
axes.set_yscale('log')
sns.distplot(x, hist=True, kde=False, bins=100, color = 'blue', hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'})
```

[image]

Different plot:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True, figsize=(20, 8))
axes.set_yscale('log')
plt.plot(x,x)
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is a better way of plotting these or it would make sense to try to take a different approach, maybe go by subfolders. I would like to display the extreme skewness in the data that we have many very small files and some medium-sized. Ideally, we would have roughly equal-sized files.

Comment: A [treemap](https://python-graph-gallery.com/200-basic-treemap-with-python/) also seems to be an interesting option. The filesize determines the surface area. Color could e.g. depend on subfolder (or filetype).

Comment: This is an excellent recommendation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choice of plots depends on what you want to communicate to the reader, so it is always a contextual issue.  Assuming that your goal is simply to give the reader a sense of the distribution of the file sizes, a histogram of the data is perfectly reasonable.  Once you add clear axis titles and a plot title, the histogram you have constructed ought to be sufficient to give the reader a clear idea of the distribution of the data.

Comment: This is what I thought. I might just split the data into smaller chunks and display histograms for those chunks as well. Thank you!